# Can the result of Gram-Schmidt process be a zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

A matrix was given and I was told to do QR-factorization of the given matrix. But, if the column vectors of the matrix are not linearly independent, i.e., linearly dependent, how can I get the matrix Q? One of the vectors q1, q2, q3, which are the results of Gram-Schmidt process should be zero-vector, then how can I proceed QR-factorization?

Comment: You might find it helpful to read the answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525895/qr-decomposition-does-q-always-have-full-column-rank. If $A$ does not have full column rank, then you can used the "reduced" $QR$ factorization, in which case (the "reduced") $Q$ will have all non-zero columns, but fewer columns than $A$.